# Add Version to Existing DLLs Maintaining Backwards Compatability

Tags: c#

I have a product that I need to add dynamic versioning to our core level components, so that the main application can check for version inconsistencies before allowing certain things to execute. Some background:

- All components implement an interface that I have defined
- There is no base class that the components derive from, they all implement the root interface directly
- I can add a new `int Version` property and/or methods to the interface
- I need to maintain backwards compatibility with DLLs that already "in the wild" and deployed. If a DLL doesn't implement the version checking APIs (because its old), assume it will work properly

So I was thinking of adding a `bool CheckVersion()` method to the interface, and then checking if that method exists before invoking it. If the method doesn't exist, then just don't invoke it.

I don't like the idea of checking if  the method exists because it is expensive and clutters up the code (e.g., "Why is this weird invocation check necessary?")

Anyone have any better ideas?

Comment: Definitely don't do that. Versioning is a pretty big topic (your question is way too broad) but when you need a new function in an existing interface, create a new interface that derives from the old one. No need for runtime checks, etc. - old code using the old interface works and new code that needs the new function will see it in the new interface.

Comment: Google for "c# interface versioning" for more details.